# c# insert data failure

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio-2013

my database seems to be connected and select queries are returning successful solutions but when I add data to my table it gives successful execution while data doesn't appear in the database

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DataHub.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
        conn.Open();

        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("select count(*) from companies",conn);
        int count = (int)comm.ExecuteScalar();
        MessageBox.Show(count.ToString());
        comm = new SqlCommand("Insert into Companies Values ( " + (count+1) + ", '" + companyName.Text + "' , '" + openDate.Text + "' , '" + companyDesc.Text + "');", conn);
        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show(companyName.Text + " Successfully Created rows: ");
        conn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: The first thing you need to do, before *anything* else, is change how you're constructing your SQL statement. Stop building it dynamically, and instead use parameterized SQL. Next, if the idea of using `count + 1` is to create an automatically-incrementing ID, I would strongly suggest you do that within the database itself.

Comment: @rexroxm `it gives successful execution while data doesn't appear in the database` sounds like no exception :)

Comment: no exceptions. It seems to execute perfectly but when I exit my application and take a peek into the table there is no new entry there.

Comment: Does your database table have exactly 4 columns? Because you are not defining your columns in the insert query, which is not recommended.

Comment: @JonSkeet before I did it just like you said using "identity" but when a row gets deleted the database doesn't reassign the sequence number rather it just ignores it

Comment: @Johan yes it has exactly 4 rows. I also tried defining but no luck

Comment: @JonSkeet I'd add that using `Insert into [Table] Values (...)` is bad practice too. If someone adds a new column to the table, the insert is going to break.

Comment: @JonSkeet comm = new SqlCommand("Insert into Companies (Id, Name, OpeningDate, Description) Values ( " + (count+1) + ", '" + companyName.Text + "' , '" + openDate.Text + "' , '" + companyDesc.Text + "');", conn); done

Comment: when I add multiple companies the count increases every time but when I exit from application and re-execute it the counter goes back to 1

Comment: It's *good* that the database doesn't reassign the sequence number. With your current scheme, if you have rows with IDs 1, 2, 3 then someone deletes row 1 and adds another row you'll have two rows with ID 3. That's awful. If it's resetting each time you start your application, that suggests you've got something that wipes the database when you stop or start your application...

Comment: got your point but I can't move on to that part until I can get data to insert into the table so pretty much stuck doing nothing :/